# What do you call the points on a circle that are vertically above/below and to the left/right of the circle centre?

Tags: geometry, terminology

On a circle, there is a point that is vertically above the centre and a point that is vertically below the centre. Likewise there is a point is to the left of the centre and to the right of the centre.

What term can be best used to describe these points?

Maximum and minimum points don't seem correct? And these would only apply to the point vertically above and the point vertically below the centre, not the ones on the same horizontal line as the centre.

What about extrema?

Comment: If you parameterize your circle, for example by $(x,y)=(x_0 + r \cos \theta,y_0 + r \sin \theta), \quad \theta \in [0,2\pi)$, then the points correspond to $\theta \in \left\{  0, \pi/2, \pi, 3\pi/2 \right\}$.

Comment: It wouldn't be unreasonable to call these the "cardinal points" on the circle, making reference to the [cardinal directions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_direction) (North, South, East, West) on a compass.